# Angular 9 | Can't bind to 'loading' since it isn't a known property of 'img'

Tags: angular, image, bind, loading

I'm using Angular 9 and I'm simple trying to bind the attribute "loading" of the img element to a Angular property. This works if I run the app in dev mode, but not in prod mode.

In my template I have this:

```
<img [src]="image" [loading]="loading" [alt]="title">
```

And in the component I have this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component(
{
    selector: 'image-card',
    templateUrl: './image-card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./image-card.component.scss'],
})
export class ImageCardComponent implements OnInit
{
    @Input() loading:"lazy" | "eager" = "lazy";
    @Input() title:string;
    @Input() image?:string;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() 
    {
        this.image = this.image || "assets/images/default_image.jpg";
    }
}
```

This is working on a dev build/ng serve, but if I run a prod build:

```
ng build --prod
```

I get the error:

> Can't bind to 'loading' since it isn't a known property of 'img'.

The property exists, https://caniuse.com/#search=loading why I'm getting the error?

How can I exclude this validation/restriction on a prod build?

For example the alt bind works fine with no errors.

EDIT: to include better code samples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `loading` attribute for images is pretty new, not supported by all browsers yet, and not Angular either. So you should try to use the `[attr.loading]="loading"` syntax until Angular considers this as a native HTML attribute.

Related line in Angular's source code: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.ts#L119

Comment: BANG... BANG... it's building... BANG... it's working! =D Thank You so much...
Didn't know that there are "unknown" valid properties to Angular... Is this the rule, to use [attr.<my-custom-and-unknown-attribute>] when there's "unknown" attributes?

Comment: Yes, it's usually for non-HTML attributes, but this will do the trick for you until Angular's ready. I update my answer with Angular's source code.

Comment: It could be that the attribute is supported by a few browsers but that the corresponding property is not defined yet in the [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).

Comment: `'loading' in HTMLImageElement.prototype` returns `true` in Chrome 80, that's an inconsistency between two Google teams :)